# Vim-R plugin shortcut to execute dev.off()

Tags: r, vim, vim-plugin, vim-r

I'm often playing around with `par()` `png()` and so on, and then I often need to manually execute a random line with `dev.off()` in order to reset all my graphical parameters.

Looking at the doc I can't find a shortcut that would allow me to do it quickly. Did I miss something? if not, is it possible to create something similar (ie a shortcut that would send `dev.off()` to R)?

Answer (score 2):

From `?par`:

> ‘par()’ (no arguments) or ‘par(no.readonly = TRUE)’ is used to get
>        *all* the graphical parameters (as a named list).  Their names are
>        currently taken from the unexported variable ‘graphics:::.Pars’.

So you can do something like:

```
#get the default values
x<-par(no.readonly=TRUE)
#set some values
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
#plot something
plot(1:10)
plot(10:1)
#reset the pars
do.call(par,x)
#new plot
plot(1:10)
```

Comment: thanks! That I supposed I should put it ad the end of my function in order to reset par with its orginial value right? my question now is more about how integrate this (so your `do.call(par,x)`) with the vim-R plugin in order that I only need to press some shortcut (`<ctrl+a>\off` or whatever) to run it whenever I want?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If your plot is in a function, consider also using `on.exit()`, which allows you to execute some commands just before exiting from a function (whether successfully or not).